# Django фильтрация и сортировка в ListView

Tags: python, django

Всех приветствую!
Есть некий список товаров, который я вывожу при помощи класса ListView:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    # Вывод всех товаров на главной странице
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 12
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
```

В шаблоне есть выпадающий список, при помощи которого необходимо отсортировывать товары:

```
<div class="box sort pull-right">
  <span>Сортировка:</span>
  <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu2">
    <span class="dropdown-label">По умолчанию</span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu2">
     <li><a href="#" title="Сброс сортировки">По умолчанию</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" title="Сортировка по возрастанию цены">Дешевле</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" title="Сортировка по убыванию цены">Дороже</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Насколько я правильно понимаю, то необходимо отправить методом GET параметр, по которому будут отсортированы товары, а во view при помощи переопределения метода get_queryset (получив параметр сортировки), вернуть обратно список товаров. 
Как это делается правильно? Или есть другие способы (без загрузки сторонних модулей) ?
**P.S.** - изначально стоит сортировка:

```
class Meta:
        ...
        ordering = ['-id']
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Гляньте [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350362/django-listview-form-to-filter-and-sort/33350839) либо [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698197/is-there-django-list-view-model-sort)

Comment: спасибо, использую в своем коде)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, благодаря подсказке @5c0rp я исправил код, исходя из потребностей задачи. **Код в шаблоне:**

```
<form action="{% url 'shop:home' %}" method="get" id="sortProduct">

  <div class="box sort pull-right">
    <span>Сортировка:</span>
    <button value="Сортировка" class="dropdown-toggle" type="submit" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu2">
     <span class="dropdown-label">По умолчанию</span>
    </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu2">
      <li><input type="submit" name="orderby" value="-id"></li>
      <li><input type="submit" name="orderby" value="price"></li>
      <li><input type="submit" name="orderby" value="-price"></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Код во views.py:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    # Вывод всех товаров на главной странице
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 12
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = 'main/index.html'

    def get_ordering(self):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('orderby')
        print(ordering)
        return ordering
```

Оставлю код тут - может кому пригодится. 
Конечно можно было бы сделать как-то по-другому: через AJAX

```
<li><a href="" onclick="javascript:sortProducts('-id');">По умолчанию</a></li>
```

а далее обрабатывать получаемый параметр сортировки и отправлять его во view.

**или**

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms['sortProduct'].submit();">Submit</a>
```

Я разобрался в сути данного метода, **но мне он не понравился**. Возможно ошибусь, но поделюсь мнением:

```
<form action="{% url 'shop:home' %}" method="get" id="sortProductById">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="-id" />
</form>
<form action="{% url 'shop:home' %}" method="get" id="sortProductByPrice">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="price"/>
</form>
<form action="{% url 'shop:home' %}" method="get" id="sortProductByPriceB">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="-price"/>
</form>

<div class="box sort pull-right">
 <span>Сортировка:</span>
 <button value="Сортировка" class="dropdown-toggle" type="submit" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu2">
   <span class="dropdown-label">По умолчанию</span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu2">
    <li><a href="#" title="Сброс сортировки" onclick="document.getElementById('sortProductById').submit();">По умолчанию</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Сортировка по возрастанию цены" onclick="document.getElementById('sortProductByPrice').submit();">Дешевле</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Сортировка по убыванию цены" onclick="document.getElementById('sortProductByPriceB').submit();">Дороже</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Получается, что к каждому параметру создается отдельная форма со скрытым полем, которое по нажатию элемента из раскрывающегося списка отправляется GET запросом. 
**Мне этот вариант совершенно не понравился - на мой взгляд чрезмерная избыточность и повторение (ИМХО).** Если у кого есть мнение по конкретно этому вопросу - поделитесь!